# Unable To Add My Android Studio Project to Github

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I Searched a lot on SO and other links too but still hang up. I am using Android Studio 1.3.2. I trying to add my Existing Android Studio Project to Github but I am facing few problems.
 What I've done so far:

- Downloaded git for windows
- Cloned the Git.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFPw4.png)

After that I am opening Setting->Version Control [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4Mvh.png) by Unable to find the Git Option.

I also tried these too but unable to find git option.

- VCS-> Import into Version Control
- VCS-> Unable Version Control Integration

but didn't find git option.
Thanks in Advance. Please ask me if you are getting anything.

Comment: I am using this link as a reference-->http://wii.logdown.com/posts/2013/11/15/android-studio-git-tutorial

Comment: but you need to give git path to android studio..did you done that?

Comment: @gvsharma How?? Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Simply Go to **Settings** Select **Plugins** now you will have All the plugins just select **Git Integration** select it. Now you have two options **Browse Repositories** and **Install plugin from disk**[image] If You Click **Browse Repositories** then you have a window open where you can install your plugin and after that your Studio will Restart and you will see the Git in your **Version Control**. Now you can add your stuff.

Comment: Let Me Try This Too!!

Comment: which repository i have to install??

Comment: .ignore(VCS Integration)

Answer (score 0):

You have origin as a remote created already, just add your stuff to the staging area using git add . then use git commit -m 'your commit message' to commit your changes, then the most important part, PUSH your master branch to your remote using git push origin master.

You should read about the git workflow, here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics, http://marklodato.github.io/visual-git-guide/index-en.html.

Answer (score -1):

here are the steps.
First go File-->Settings--->in the leftpane--> click on Version controle.
You will find Git and Github.

Click on Git and give your git.exe path

Click on Github enter your github credentials and host as github.com.

Click on apply and Ok.
Then you can able to find version control option under tools

Comment: Have you seen the image i attached with my question. I am not getting Git or Github option in Version Control.

Comment: it will work...you will find git and github under the path that i mentioned..
and once you gave them the path then android studio will restart and you will get git under version control